# How to set compiler correctly in build.sh for building VLC in iOS

Tags: ios, c

Whenever I tried to change `CC and CPP in build.sh(ImportedSources/VLCKit/MobileVLCKit/ImportedSources/vlc/extras/package/ios)`

**This error comes**

```
"Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them."
```

What is the right way to change CC and CPP path? I am trying to build VLC for iOS.
But "C compiler not working message" comes every time I build for device(for simulator it works fine). I found an answer from VLC forum that this might be due to xcrun points to wrong compiler (https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=117736).

But I can't change path in build.sh:( . Is there another way to deal with this error.
Where can I change the compiler path so that my C compiler works. I have searched a lot for this error, still no luck. Please provide some guidance.

Thanks,

Sibinesh M.C

Comment: have you tried to set the C compiler for your current terminal session, i.e. if your using BASH, `export CC=/path/to/gcc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the existing and repull.

Next time just check that you are using zsh or iTerm2 (recommended by VLC). Also check the path expected by script file is same as yours. If not add by sudo.

I also faced the same issue, but setting the path by sudo does the job for me.